# Getting quote exceeded message when trying to get c2-standard-60

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm currently on the Google Cloud free $300 and 90 days trial. I wanted to get c2-standard-60 server in us-west2 to run my behavioral algorithms on it. But I'm getting quote exceeded limit. How do I solve it?

Comment: Did you upgrade to a paid account? If no, you will not be able to use those resources. The solution is to request a quota increase which requires an upgraded account. If yes, @jccampanero's answer will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification @JohnHanley, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can review your quotas limits under the `Quotas` option in the `IAM & Admin` menu in the Google Cloud Web console.

Then, search for service `Compute Engine API` and `Limit name` `C2 CPUS`: it will give you your current quota limit.

Probably it will be around `24` CPUs for region, maybe less if you are using the free tier, and the machine type `c2-standard-60` requires `60`.

If necessary, you can request a quota increase. See the [relevant documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas).

Comment: Do I get notified if I my quote change request gets rejected?

Comment: Hi @A.Bokizh. Yes, you should be notified if the quota increase is approved or rejected. I hope they allow you to make use of the resources you need.